# Using Automatic Entity Label how to add number if title is already used (unique)

Tags: forms, entities, nodes

I have setup auto entity label with tokens. All works great.
Lets say I have a title
e.g. tokens
[firstname] [lastname]

Displayed as:
Tom Cruise

But if there are multiple identical titles named "Tom Cruise".
e.g.

node 65: Tom Cruise
node 90: Tom Cruise
node 23: Tom Cruise

What I want is it to validate, the title is not unique therefore add number on the end.

node 65: Tom Cruise
node 90: Tom Cruise 1
node 23: Tom Cruise 2

Or something like that. I have been using nid / serial field to make them unique but that isn't what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You can add node id to the label. It will make labels unique anyway.
For example

```
[node:field_first_name] [node:field_last_name] #[node:nid]
```

Please note, that there is an issue in module that prevents [node:nid] token from working.
https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_entitylabel/issues/2920695

But there is simple patch available in this issue to fix this. So this should be resolved soon I hope. Until that you need to apply patch manually.
https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2018-11-11/auto_entitylabel-support_entity_id-2920695-31.patch